# Determining data input is a valid URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, razor

I have several views in an MVC3 project that allow a user to enter a Url into a text input and save it as data on an entity.

We need to validate that the input is a validly formed Url.

I first started with using the `[Url]` annotation from http://dataannotationsextensions.org/ but for some strange reason, the client-side validation fails if the user inputs any uppercase characters. So to alleviate that I added a jQuery event that forces the input to lowercase as the user types. Turns out this isn't optimal either because the user can paste in a Url that has been shortened by a Url shortening service such as tinyUrl, etc. and those uppercase characters are necessary for the translation.

So I went instead with a regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid Url")]
```

This works fine for allowing uppercase characters. But it's not perfect. With this Regex these are all considered valid:

1. www.asp
2. asp.net
3. http://asp.net
4. http://www.asp.net
5. http://www.asp

As you can see, some of these aren't truly valid.

The biggest problem with these Urls is when displaying the Url back in a Display View. If the Url text does not have the `http://` prepended to the Url then the link that is created in the View ends up looking like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/controller/action/www.asp
```

or

```
http://www.mydomain.com/controller/action/asp.net
```

which are both invalid obviously.

For example, this bit of Razor code will create a link like the two above if the Url does not have `http://` prepended

```
....
<a href="@item.Link" target="blank">@item.LinkName</a>
...
```

But if the entered Url has `http://` prepended the Url generated in the display view actually is a real Url such as

```
http://www.asp.net
http://asp.net
http://www.asp - this is actually an invalid address as well but it renders out correctly.
```

Surely, showing a Url that was saved into a db and then shown on a View isn't as difficult as this and also allowing a user to save a well formed Url but also abbreviating it such as:

```
asp.net
www.asp.net
```

without having to include the prepended protocol.

**Update**

Here is the definition of my Url field in my ViewModel using the annotation from http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

```
[Required]
[StringLength(128)]
[Url(false)] // false denotes whether the protocol is required or not
public string URL { get; set; }
```

So you don't think I'm nuts, here is a screenshot using uppercase and no uppercase. Tested in IE8 and Chrome so far and I get the same results

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which of those 5 examples aren't truly valid? OK, they may not all _resolve_ but if you wanted to test that you can do away with Regex and just ping them.

Comment: 1 and 5 are completely invalid as there's no way to get to that address, although 5 with create a Url, just not navigable. 2, 3 and 4 are valid but only 3 and 4 (with the prepended http:// are navigable, anything without http:// creates a bad navigable Url as shown above with the `http://www.mydomain.com/controller/action/www.asp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the 2 DLLs DataAnnotationsExtensions.dll and DataAnnotationsExtensions.ClientValidation.dll from http://dataannotationsextensions.org/ that I was using were version 1.0 and did not allow for uppercasing in the `[Url]` annotation. I updated to version 1.1 on both as this is the version demo'd on the website and the problem is now fixed.

Using `[Url]` will now allow me to enforce `http://` if I absolutely have to as well as allowing uppercase characters.

Using `[Url(false)]` will allow the user to not have to enter `http://` and I can prepend it in code.

Answer (score 0):

`[Url]` from  http://dataannotationsextensions.org/ works perfectly fine for me with uppercase letters. But if for some reason you don't want to use it you could plagiarize the Regex it uses:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-fA-F]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-zA-Z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-zA-Z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-fA-F]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-fA-F]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-fA-F]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-zA-Z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-fA-F]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why did you pass false to the Url constructor? This is contradictory to your requirement that you need to enforce the protocol.

Comment: That was testing both scenarios. I don't want to have to force the user to enter the protocol unless I absolutely have to. Most of our users will be entering `www.mybankname.com` or `myschoolname.edu`

Comment: This Regex also fails when entering any uppercase characters... :-(